# Getting NULL value for async function (after using await) then updating to the new value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, async-await, future

When I run my app it throws a lot of errors, and the red/yellow error screen on my device, which refreshes automatically and shows me the expected output then.

From the log I can see that first my object is return as null, which somehow later updates and I get the output.

I have recently started Android Dev (Flutter)

I tried to follow a number of online guides and also read related questions on async responses but no troubleshooting has been helping me.
My biggest problem being that I can't figure out what exactly is the problem.

In my _AppState class:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() async {
    var cityUrl = "http://ip-api.com/json/";
    var cityRes = await http.get(cityUrl);
    var cityDecodedJson = jsonDecode(cityRes.body);
    weatherCity = WeatherCity.fromJson(cityDecodedJson);
    print(weatherCity.city);
    var weatherUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
        weatherCity.city +
        "," +
        weatherCity.countryCode +
        "&appid=" +
        //Calling open weather map's API key from apikey.dart
        weatherKey;
    var res = await http.get(weatherUrl);
    var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    weatherData = WeatherData.fromJson(decodedJson);
    print(weatherData.weather[0].main);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Expected output (Terminal):

```
Mumbai
Rain
```

Actual output (Terminal): https://gist.github.com/Purukitto/99ffe63666471e2bf1705cb357c2ea32 (Actual error was crossing the body limit of StackOverflow)

ScreenShots:
[image: At run initial]
[image: After a few seconds]

Comment: Could you please print content of decodedJson and content of weatherData to make sure the data exists?

Comment: the problem is straightforward...the `fetchData` function is async so it doesn't stop the widget from building. And when it builds first, the `weatherData` is null. But after some time the API call gives some response and then you call setState and this time it works because now `weatherData` is not null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `async` and `await` is a mechanism for handling Asynchronous programming in Dart.

> Asynchronous operations let your program complete work while waiting
>   for another operation to finish.

So whenever a method is marked as `async`, your program does not pause for completion of the method and just assumes that it will complete at some point in the future.

**Example: Incorrectly using an asynchronous function**

The following example shows the wrong way to use an asynchronous function `getUserOrder()`.

```
String createOrderMessage () {
  var order = getUserOrder(); 
  return 'Your order is: $order';
}

Future<String> getUserOrder() {
  // Imagine that this function is more complex and slow
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () => 'Large Latte'); 
}

main () {
  print(createOrderMessage());
}
```

If you run the above program it will produce the below output -

```
Your order is: Instance of '_Future<String>'
```

This is because, since the return type of the method is marked as [Future](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.1/dart-async/Future-class.html), the program will treat is as an asynchronous method.

To get the user’s order, `createOrderMessage()` should call `getUserOrder()` and wait for it to finish. Because `createOrderMessage()` does not wait for `getUserOrder()` to finish, `createOrderMessage()` fails to get the string value that `getUserOrder()` eventually provides.

---

**Async and await**

The async and await keywords provide a declarative way to define asynchronous functions and use their results.

So whenever you declare a function to be `async`, you can use the keyword `await` before any method call which will force the program to not proceed further until the method has completed.

---

**Case in point**

In your case, the `fetchData()` function is marked as `async` and you are using `await` to wait for the network calls to complete.

But here `fetchData()` has a return type of `Future<void>` and hence when you call the method inside `initState()` you have to do so without using `async/ await` since `initState()` cannot be marked `async`.

So the program does not wait for completion of the `fetchData()` method as a whole and tries to display data which is essentially `null`.
And since you call `setState()` after the data is loaded inside `fetchData()`, the screen refreshes and you can see the details after some time.

Hence the red and yellow screen error.

---

**Solution**

The solution to this problem is you can show a loading indicator on the screen until the data is loaded completely.

You can use a `bool` variable and change the UI depending the value of that variable.

**Example -**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isLoading = false;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
 }

 fetchData() async {
   setState(() {
     isLoading = true; //Data is loading
   });
   var cityUrl = "http://ip-api.com/json/";
   var cityRes = await http.get(cityUrl);
   var cityDecodedJson = jsonDecode(cityRes.body);
   weatherCity = WeatherCity.fromJson(cityDecodedJson);
   print(weatherCity.city);
   var weatherUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + weatherCity.city + "," +
    weatherCity.countryCode +
    "&appid=" +
    //Calling open weather map's API key from apikey.dart
    weatherKey;
    var res = await http.get(weatherUrl);
    var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    weatherData = WeatherData.fromJson(decodedJson);
    print(weatherData.weather[0].main);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false; //Data has loaded
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading ? Center(child : CircularProgressIndicator())
      : Container(), //Replace this line with your actual UI code
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I chose to put the condition while returning the Scaffold instead of the body as I was also using the value in the AppBar

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the data from api arrive. The quick fix is to place a null-coalescing operator on the variable that hold the future data like this:

```
String text;

fetchData() async {
//...
  text = weatherData.weather[0].main ?? 'Waiting api response...';
//...
}

// in your build method
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: Text(text), //this will render "Waiting api response" first, and when the api result arrive, it will change
    ),
  );
}
```

Otherwise, you could use the `futureBuilder` widget to achieve that. But you must place each api to different function, and change that to Future, so it has a return value.

```
Future fetchDataCity() async {
  // your code
  weatherCity = WeatherCity.fromJson(cityDecodedJson);
  return weatherCity;
}

Future fetchDataWeather() async {
  // your code
  weatherData = WeatherData.fromJson(decodedJson);
  return weatherData;
}

// in your build method
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchDataWeather(), // a previously-obtained Future or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState)
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Awaiting result...'); //or a placeholder
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError){
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.data}');
            }
         },
      ) //FutureBuilder
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight , though this seems like it would work I found @siddharth-patankar 's answer easier to understand