# How to prevent a Flutter app from routing to an incorrect page?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building a Flutter app that incorporates **Role Based Authorization** and I'm confused as why my app sends a person with the role `user` to the Dashboard screen which is only meant for people who have the `teacher` role.

Note: This is a huge security pothole right now. The user should never even know that this Dashboard exists. I expect my app to immediately fetch the user document from Cloud Firestore and read their role. If their role is a user, send them over to the home screen. Else, the role has to be a teacher, so send them over to the teacher Dashboard.

What I'm seeing: My app sends a normal user to the dashboard for ~2 seconds then loads a bit and then takes them to the HomeScreen. This means that a normal user can see the Dashboard screen which should not happen!

Here is my code below:

```
bool isUser = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authService = Provider.of < FirebaseAuthService > (context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder < User > (
        stream: authService.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                var user;
                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                    user = snapshot.data;
                    populateUserInfo(context, user.uid);
                }

                if (user == null) {
                    return LoginScreen();
                } else {
                    if (isUser) return HomeScreen();
                    else return DashboardScreen();
                }
            } else {
                return Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                    )
                );
            }
        },
    );
}

Future < void > populateUserInfo(BuildContext context, String uid) async {
    final database = Provider.of < FirestoreService > (context, listen: false);
    isUser = await database.isUser(uid);
}
```

Perhaps a workaround is to set a manual delay in the app for a fixed amount of time, but that solution seems very hand-wavy and insecure. I'm not sure if this is an emulator issue because it needs to sync the files after I build the app.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

**EDIT (Follow-up question)** - Is there a way to run an asynchronous task in a StreamBuilder without returning a null widget?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your app is waiting for the future to be resolved, and once it does, it corrects the permissions and your app behaves correctly. And this is happening because your condition is on the syncronous part of your code. You could fix it by adding the conditions to the asyncronous part by doing something like this:

```
if (snapshot.data != null) {
    user = snapshot.data;
    populateUserInfo(context, user.uid).then((bool value) => {
        isUser = value;
        if (user == null) {
            return LoginScreen();
        } else {
            if (isUser) return HomeScreen();
            else return DashboardScreen();
        }
    });
}else{
    // you logic in case the snapshot is null
}
```

Also, you would have to change the populateUserInfo function to:

```
Future < bool > populateUserInfo(BuildContext context, String uid) async {
    final database = Provider.of < FirestoreService > (context, listen: false);
    return await database.isUser(uid);
}
```

**NOTE**: This is untested but it should be a good starting point to fixing it if it does not work right away.

Comment: Going of your code I get an error that says "Build functions must never return null". Do you know if there is a way to set async await in a StreamBuilder?

Comment: Update - I managed to get rid of that bug and implement the Promise, but I always get sent to the LoginScreen() regardless. Please take a look at my dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/bd2d5f08cd45865d8383234d0739cb80

Comment: Isn't there an extra `return LoginScreen();` that is causing that? From what I see on the dartpad the final return, who is outside your condition and it's always executed, is causing this, remove it and let me know if this works

Comment: If I remove that I get an Exception. The gist of the exception is that build functions can never return null. That's why I added LoginScreen() to the end.

Comment: In this [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551482/getting-null-value-for-async-function-after-using-await-then-updating-to-the-n) there is a similar problem to your, the solution proposed was to use a loading indicator, since the async function will not wait for the completion of the future. That is what I would suggest on your case as well

Comment: Okay great, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Tried that solution. Although relevant, there are many things that prevent that solution from working in my case. I'm using a StreamBuilder, so I can not use a setState anywhere inside. As a result, I can't render a loading animation. I can't fetch any user data before the Streambuilder because I need the user's UID and the current build context in order to fetch their role from Firestore. The only place I can get that data is from the onAuthStateChanged stream. Is there a totally different approach to this problem I'm not seeing? This is such an essential and common feature.

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to resolve this issue.